# didBegin contact not being called in Swift

Tags: swift, collision-detection, game-physics

I have two nodes, and I want to detect a collision between them, but for some reason

`func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {`

is not being called.

It is a ball and a paddle:

```
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2        
ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

main.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
main.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
main.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
```

_

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("Collision") //Obviously this will be better in future, but I need to detect collision for a start
}
```

When the ball moves around, it DOES bounce off the paddle, but I need to be able to detect that.

Thanks

Comment: Check out how they do it at [Ray Wenderlich's](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1161-how-to-make-a-breakout-game-with-spritekit-and-swift-part-1)

Answer (score 4):

check these things:

Make sure you set the physics world contact delegate to itself
        class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    }
```

if you had specified a physics body eg:

```
box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize)
```

make sure it's definitely unwrapped (! not ?)

```
box.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
```

Make the physics bodies dynamic:

```
    box.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
```

Comment: HOLY DUDE THATNK YOU SO MUCH OMFG IVE BEEN TRYING TO GET THIS TO WORK FOR 4 DAYS NOW!!!!! THANK YOUUUU

Comment: You don't have to have `isDynamic = true`

Answer (score 0):

In the `init()` method of your `GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate` object, make sure to assign the `contactedDelegate` attribute of the `physicsWorld` variable to your scene (here `self`):

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self // Most important part!
    }

    internal func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("Collision!") // Now every objects colliding within self will call didBegin()
    }
}
```

Hope this help and is more self-explanatory, have a nice day ma bro.